# Google Cloud Messaging in dart

Tags: dart, google-chrome-app, chromium, chrome-gcm

I'm trying to connect to the Google Cloud Messaging with this code in dart

```
  senderIds.add("api-project-testid");
  chrome.gcm.register(senderIds).then(registerCallback);
```

but I have this error:

> Exception: Uncaught Error: Profile was not signed in.

I think that the error arises from the fact that chromium is not connected with any account. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... The version Dartium used in DartEditor is `39.0.2171.0`  To use `chrome.gcm.register` (senderIds) without user logged must have at least version 40. You have to import the package in an updated version of chrome.

I hope it can help someone otherwise I can delete.